# Agregar un polígono de la librería geovoronoi en un mapa de la librería Folium en Python

Tags: python, google-colab, folium

Para crear un polígono de Voronoi con geovoronoi lib, uso:

```
polyShapes, puntos = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, milagroShape)
```

**coords** es un objeto geoDataFrame que contiene las ubicaciones del mapa y **milagroShape** es un polygon.shp. Ahora, para trazar el Voronoi uso el código:

```
fig, ax = subplot_for_map(figsize=[14, 8])
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, milagroShape, polyShapes, coords, puntos)
ax.set_title('Diagrama de Voronoi')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Ahora funciona, el gráfico se muestra en la pantalla, pero es solo un diagrama de mathplotlib.
[image: Diagrama de Voronoi dibujado con mathplotlib]

Supongo que tengo que convertirlo en un objeto de geodataframe (para eso, uso la librería de geopandas). Este es el mapa donde necesito poner el gráfico de Voronoi:[image: Mapa donde quiero insertar el diagrama de voronoi]

Solo está agregadp el polígono del área de la ciudad, pero también quiero agregar el Voronoi. Para agregar el área de la ciudad utilicé el siguiente código:

```
for _, r in milagro.iterrows(): #milagro es un objeto geodataframe
#sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry'])
sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r['geometry']).simplify(tolerance=0.0001)
geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                   style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'})
#folium.Popup(r['Name']).add_to(geo_j)
geo_j.add_to(mapaMilagro) #mapaMilagro is a folium map object
```

Las librerías que utilizo para mi proyecto son:

```
import folium #map library
import pandas as pd #Data Frame 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #to plot graphs
import condacolab #To install some libraries
import geopandas as gpd #Geo Data Frame library
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union #I don´t know what is this xd
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta, que error o fallo tienes?

Comment: Quiero agregar el gráfico del diagrama de voronoi al mapa. Tengo poco conocimiento sobre las librerías, no se como hacer. Creo que podría convertir el geovoronoi en un geodataframe para agregarlo al mapa. El código no contiene errores, los puse como referencia para explicar que es lo que estoy haciendo. Ya que no se cómo agregar el diagrama de Voronoi al mapa.